# Form is not taking values ​from querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a "piggy bank" project that saves and withdraws an amount of money passed through two different forms (Each modal is for one type of transaction), but when trying to withdraw, the values ​​are empty as in the example:

```
{date: "", amount: "", type: "Retirada"}
```

When saving the values ​​normally:

```
{date: "2021-02-27", amount: "1", type: "Depósito"}
```

I'm not able to find the error of not taking the values

**Snipped Code**:

```js
const Modals = {
    modalType: "",
    openModals(type){
        if(type == "Depósito") {
            this.modalType = type;
            document.querySelector('.modal1-overlay').classList.add('active')
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.modal2-overlay').classList.add('active')
            this.modalType = type;
        }
    },
    closeModals(type) {
        if(type == "Depósito") {
            document.querySelector('.modal1-overlay').classList.remove('active')
            this.modalType = "";
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.modal2-overlay').classList.remove('active')
            this.modalType = "";
        }
    },
    openErrorModal(message) {
        document.querySelector('.modalError-overlay').classList.add('active')
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = message
    },
    closeErrorModal() {
        document.querySelector('.modalError-overlay').classList.remove('active')
    }
}

const Transaction = {
    all: [],

    add(transaction) {
        Transaction.all.push(transaction)
        App.reload()
    },

    totalBalance() {
        let total = 0;
        Transaction.all.forEach(transaction => {
            if (transaction.type == "Retirada") {
                total -= transaction.amount;
            } else {
                total += transaction.amount;
            }
        })
        return total;
    },
}

const DOM = {
    transactionsContainer: document.querySelector('#data-table tbody'),

    addTransaction(transaction, index) {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = this.innerHTMLTransaction(transaction);
        this.transactionsContainer.appendChild(tr)
    },

    innerHTMLTransaction(transaction) {
        const CSSclass = transaction.type === 'Retirada' ? "withdraw" : "income"

        const amount = Utils.formatCurrency(transaction.amount, transaction.type)

        const html = `
        <tr>
            <td class="${CSSclass}">${transaction.type}</td>
            <td class="price-transaction">${amount}</td>
            <td class="date">${transaction.date}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        `;

        return html;
    },

    updateBalance() {
        document
            .getElementById("totalCurrency")
            .innerHTML = Utils.formatCurrency(Transaction.totalBalance())
    },

    clearTransactions() {
        DOM.transactionsContainer.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

const Utils = {
    formatAmount(value) {
        value = Number(value)*100
        return value;
    },

    formatDate(date){
        const splittedDate = date.split("-")
        return `${splittedDate[2]}/${splittedDate[1]}/${splittedDate[0]}`
    },

    formatCurrency(value, type) {
        if (type == "Retirada") {
            value = String(value).replace(/\D/g, "");
            value = Number(value) / 100
            value = value.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {style: "currency", currency: "BRL"})
            return "- " + value;
        } else {
            const signal = "";
            value = String(value).replace(/\D/g, "");
            value = Number(value) / 100
            value = value.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {style: "currency", currency: "BRL"})
            return value
        }
    }
}

const Form = {
    amount: Modals.modalType == "Retirada" ? document.querySelector('input#amount2') : document.querySelector('input#amount'),
    date: Modals.modalType == "Retirada" ? document.querySelector('input#date2') : document.querySelector('input#date'),

    getValues() {
        return {
            date: this.date.value,
            amount: this.amount.value,
            type: Modals.modalType
        }
    },
    validateField() {
        const {date, amount, type} = Form.getValues()
        if(date.trim() === "" || amount.trim() === "" || type.trim() === "") {
            throw new Error("Por favor, preencha todos os campos!")
        }
    },

    formatValues() {
        let { date, amount, type} = Form.getValues()
        amount = Utils.formatAmount(amount)
        date = Utils.formatDate(date)
        return {date, amount, type}
    },

    clearFieldsForm(){
        Form.amount.value = "";
        Form.date.value = "";
        Modals.modalType = "";
    },

    submit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        try {
            console.log(this.getValues())
            // Form.validateField()
            const transaction = Form.formatValues()
            Transaction.add(transaction)
            Modals.closeModals(Modals.modalType)
            Form.clearFieldsForm();            
        } catch (error) {
            Modals.openErrorModal(error.message)
        }
    }
}

const App = {
    init() {
        Transaction.all.forEach(transaction => {
            DOM.addTransaction(transaction)

        });
        DOM.updateBalance()
    },
    reload() {
        DOM.clearTransactions()
        App.init()
    }
}
App.init()
```

```css
/* Global CSS */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --darkblue: #363f5f;
    --green: rgb(0, 172, 0);
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-width: 0;
}

.container {
    width: min(90vw, 800px);
    margin: auto;
}
/* Header */
header {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 2rem 2rem 5rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/* Modal CSS */
.modal1-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.modal1-overlay.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.modal1 {
    background:snow;
    padding: 2.4rem;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.modal2-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.modal2-overlay.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.modal2 {
    background:snow;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 2.4rem;
    position: relative;
}

#form {
    max-width: 500px;

}

#form h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.modalError-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.modalError-overlay.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
    visibility: visible;
}

.modalErrorContainer {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 70vh;
    height: 16vh;
    padding: 10px;
}

.modalErrorContainer h3 {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-group {
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
}

.input-group small {
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.input-group.actions {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-group.actions .button,
.input-group.actions button {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Main CSS */
#logo {
    width: 40vh;
    margin-left: -2vh;
}

#balance {
    margin-top: -3rem;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h2 { 
    font-weight: 400;
    user-select: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

h3 {
    color: black;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.527);
}

.card h3 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    user-select: none;
}

.card p {
    margin-left: 1.5vw;
    color: var(--darkblue);
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.card.total {
    background: rgb(0, 190, 0);
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.card.total p {
    color: white;
}

.card.total h3 {
    color: white;
}

.containerButtons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 1.5vh;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.button.save {
    color: var(--green);
}

.button.withdraw {
    color: red;
}

.button.ok {
    color: white;
    background-color: var(--green);
    margin-left: 85%;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: var(--green);
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
}

button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px green;
}

.button.cancel {
    color: red;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#data-table {
    border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
    color: black;
}

#data-table th {
    background: white;
    color: #646464;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: left;
}

#data-table tbody tr{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#data-table tbody tr:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

#data-table td {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

td.price-transaction {
    color: var(--darkblue);
}

td.withdraw {
    color: red;
}

td.income {
    color: green;
}

td.date {
    color: var(--darkblue);
}

td.moneyatbank {
    color: var(--darkblue);
}

/* Responsive */
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #balance {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    .card {
        margin-right: 2.5vh;

    }

    .card.total {
        margin-left: 2.5vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #data-table {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
        color: black;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo BiggyBank" id="logo">
    </header>
    <main class="container">
        <section id="balance">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Balanço</h2>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Meta</h3>
                <p>R$ 2000,00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card total">
                <h3>Total</h3>
                <p id="totalCurrency"></p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="transaction">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Transações</h2>
            <div class="containerButtons">
                <a href="#" class="button save" onclick="Modals.openModals('Depósito')">+ Guardar</a>
                <a href="#" class="button withdraw" onclick="Modals.openModals('Retirada')">- Retirar</a>
            </div>
            <table id="data-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tipo</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <img src="assets/darkmode.svg" alt="Icone DarkMode">
        <img src="assets/lightmode.svg" alt="Icone DarkMode">
    </footer>
<div class="modal1-overlay">
    <div class="modal1">
        <div id="form">
            <h2>Guardar Dinheiro</h2>
            <form action="" onsubmit="Form.submit(event)" id="form1">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="amount">Valor à ser guardado</label>
                    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Valor à ser guardado" />
                    <small class="helpText">Use a vírgula (,) para casas decimais</small>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="date">Valor à ser guardado</label>
                    <input id="date" name="date" type="date" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group actions">
                    <a href="#" class="button cancel" onclick="Modals.closeModals('Depósito')">Cancelar</a>
                    <button>Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal2-overlay">
    <div class="modal2">
        <div id="form">
            <h2>Retirar Dinheiro</h2>
            <form action="" onsubmit="Form.submit(event)" id="form2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="amount2">Valor à ser guardado</label>
                    <input id="amount2" name="amount2" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Valor à ser guardado" />
                    <small class="helpText">Use a vírgula (,) para casas decimais</small>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="date2">Valor à ser guardado</label>
                    <input id="date2" name="date2" type="date" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group actions">
                    <a href="#" class="button cancel" onclick="Modals.closeModals('Retirada')">Cancelar</a>
                    <button>Retirar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="modalError-overlay">
        <div class="modalErrorContainer">
            <h3 id="errorMessage"></h3>
            <a href="#" class="button ok" onclick="Modals.closeErrorModal()">OK</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a live code example (like jsfiddle or codepen)

Comment: I post at repl.it https://repl.it/join/ftxzcxis-ikaneskii

Comment: I'd suggest you create a live code example using the HTML/CSS/Javascript snippet on stack overflow. Since repl.it requires an account and could be taken offline in the future, meaning this question would lose its value.

Comment: Ok, so, I created the snipped code right now and i'm waiting for a help

Comment: When you use the check on `Modals.modalType == "Retirada"`, Modals.modalType is undefined, so the result of the condition is always the same. I changed the code so that your example works, here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/andrei0x309/u9jgx0s2/32/